# Tomcat UI for windows Installation

Tags: java, tomcat, windows-installer

As tomcat server is completely developed in Java, yet its installation file(.exe) are available for windows. As tomcat is open source, does the process of converting this java server application into windows installation file also documented anywhere. Which tool they use and how its works. How have they created UI wizard to take user inputs and do the registry entry and install tomcat as service.

Regards

Comment: I see that this ques has been put on hold. Well I just needed few leads on how tomcat server is converted into .exe, It must be documented some where which is what I sought. Don't need whole desc just basic intro nad few helpful links from where I carry out my research. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They use [Nullsoft Installer](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) called from the ant build.

The nsi script can be found [on svn](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/tomcat/tc7.0.x/trunk/res/tomcat.nsi?revision=1615725&view=markup), as well as all of tomcat code.

Comment: Thanks Cedric... I must dig deeper now as I know the tool now.. Thanks Again !!!